# I don't understand what he wants

Tags: c

The question is from "The C programming language" book and it reads "Write a program to determine the ranges of char, int, short, and long variables both signed and unsigned, by printing the appropriate values from standard headers or by direct computation."

My first problem is that I don't understand how can i directly print the values from standard headers... I don't even know what they are, I think i might have missed them while reading. And my second problem is I don't understand what he means by direct computation.

sorry if its a stupid question, I'm fairly new to programming.

Comment: The standard headers provide facilities to determine the maximal and minimal values of the fundamental types. Go find them.

Comment: Re-read the book ro get a different one. Not every book is suitable for every user (that's why recommendations tend to end up in heavy discussions). OTOH, I think doing some research on your own is part of the lesson. So: what have you done so far?

Comment: i've tried doing some research but i've only found solutions with very little to no explanations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right above this exercise in *The C Programming Language* it says:

> The standard headers `<limits.h>` and `<float.h>` contain symbolic constants for all of these sizes, along with other properties of the machine and compiler. These are discussed in Appendix B.

So, see Appendix B (page 257 in the second edition I have). =)

Comment: (If this still doesn't help, re-read earlier parts of the book. Also remember that the book has an index, which I used to find the above quote and the exercise you were referring to.)

Comment: Alright that answers my first question thanks :) but i still don't understand what he means by direct computation

Comment: @M_Prince Instead of using the standard header you could find out some of these values by computing them (e.g., with `unsigned` types you could add one repeatedly until the value wraps around to 0; the previous value was the maximum – with signed types this would be undefined behaviour, though).

Comment: I think i got it :D thanks for you help @Arkku :)

Comment: This is a good answer

Comment: re. my above comment, I wish to clarify that the method I described for computing the maximum value of an `unsigned` integer type is _not_ a particularly good one, but it may be the easiest one to understand. If you wish to learn more, try to find out at least three different ways to compute the maximum value of an `unsigned int` without using the headers. =)